# Windows 7 Close, Minimize & Maximize Buttons Font Family

Tags: fonts, operating-system

I am developing an Operating System. Could some tell me the font family used for the Windows 7 close, minimize and maximize buttons. (I am using an aero theme for my OS similar to Windows 7). I have tried Segeo MDL2 Assests but I still can't find the right icons.

Comment: Are you sure they're "fonts" and not just "images"?

Comment: Yes, I figured it out. They're part of the Webdings and Segoe MDL2 Assets, but you have to press WINDOWS+R, to open the run shell, and type 'charmap'. Select Segoe MDL2 Assets and copy and paste into your text or use the assets font code and put it into your code.